# How to use a string column with pgfplotstable to label datapoints in a pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a comma-separated list of data points. They should be plotted as a scatter plot, and should be labeled using data from the .csv file. Having specified the first column of my file as `string type`, I still keep running into errors saying `Could not parse input [...] as a floating point number, sorry.`

Given a CSV file of the following format, how can I read `Name` and `Z` as labels?

```
Name,X,Y,Z
ODIN,250,45,2001
```

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns/Name/.style={string type}]{table.csv};

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    visualization depends on=\thisrow{Name} \as \labela,
    visualization depends on=\thisrow{Z} \as \labelb,
    every node near coord/.append style={font={\tiny}},
    nodes near coords=\labela/\labelb,
    nodes near coords align={horizontal},]

    \addplot[only marks] table [x=X,y=Y,col sep=comma] {table.csv};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that if the data in column `Name` is just floats it should work fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add `value` prefix if you don't want the contents to be parsed as numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.csv}
Name,X,Y,Z
ODIN,250,45,2001
NIDO,280,70,2002
DINO,270,60,2003
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/set thousands separator={}}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns/Name/.style={string type},col sep=comma]{table.csv}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Name} \as \labela}, % note the value prefix
    visualization depends on={\thisrow{Z} \as \labelb},
    every node near coord/.append style={font={\tiny}},
    nodes near coords={\labela/\pgfmathprintnumber\labelb},
    nodes near coords align={horizontal}
        ]

    \addplot[scatter,only marks] table [x=X,y=Y,col sep=comma] {table.csv};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great to know, thanks. Can you tell me how you found that out?

Comment: @Ingo I've struggled with this before. It's also in the manual (at the top of page 284 ver. 1.5.1) Much easier when you know what to look for :)