# How can I add color AND a node label to a scatter plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pgfplots, metadata

I'd like to produce a scatter plot from a data file. The data file could look like this:

```
 x       y       color   myvalue
 0.5     0.2     1       test
 0.2     0.1     2       uniform
```

I'd like to add the string data in column `myvalue` to the nodes, but still have the option to colour the marks. I tried two things recommended in the manual:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[% scatter/use mapped color={draw=black,fill=mapped color},
              enlargelimits=0.2]
    \addplot[scatter, mark=*,only marks, 
            scatter src=explicit symbolic,
            nodes near coords,]
      table [x=x, y=y, meta=myvalue] {tab.tbl};

   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This allows me to put the labels to the marker in the plot.

[image: first attempt]

But I don't know how to add colours. My second attempt was to use the colour for the point meta data (manual page 88), but then I couldn't add text (it would only accept numbers in the failing code below):

```
% same preamble 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2]
     \addplot[scatter, mark=*,only marks,
              scatter src=explicit symbolic,
           % we use ’point meta’ as color data...
           point meta=\thisrow{color},
           % ... therefore, we can’t use it as argument for nodes near coords ..
           nodes near coords*={\myvalue},
           % ... which requires to define a visualization dependency:
           visualization depends on={\thisrow{myvalue} \as \myvalue},
           ]
           table [x=x, y=y, meta=myvalue] {tab.tbl};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I have both?

Answer (score 10):

oh, I found the solution in a related question.

[How to use a string column to label datapoints in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60258/how-to-use-a-string-column-with-pgfplotstable-to-label-datapoints-in-a-pgfplot?rq=1).

The key is to use `value` in front of the macro definition.

The working code is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[% scatter/use mapped color={draw=black,fill=mapped color},
              enlargelimits=0.2]
     \addplot[scatter, mark=*,only marks,
           % we use ’point meta’ as color data...
           point meta=\thisrow{color},
           % ... therefore, we can’t use it as argument for nodes near coords
           nodes near coords*={\myvalue},
           % ... which requires to define a visualization dependency:
           visualization depends on={value \thisrow{myvalue} \as \myvalue},
           ]
           table [x=x, y=y]
           {tab.tbl};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: colored]

Comment: done. I created the pictures from inside a beamer documentclass, but standalone works as well and requires less overhead.