# String annotations to scatter plot coming from a different file

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am trying to adapt the setup to be found in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60258/how-to-use-a-string-column-with-pgfplotstable-to-label-datapoints-in-a-pgfplot).
to the case where the names are in a different file.
The main motivation is to have the same names for several plots and to
be able to change them without altering the data files.

I tried to use the method to add a column from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53227/plots-with-data-coming-from-different-files) and
produces the code below.
I get the following error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
```

which I fail to interpret.
How can it be done?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/names/.style={
        create col/copy column from table={names.dat}{names}
      }
  }
    \begin{axis}[
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{names} \as \labela},
    nodes near coords={\labela},
        ]

    \addplot[scatter,only marks] table [x expr=\thisrowno{0},y expr=\thisrowno{1}] {data.dat};


    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

data.dat:

```
1 1
2 4
3 7
```

names.dat:

```
Xyzzy
Plugh
Sheng
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work directly, unfortunately, because the `create on use` doesn't play well with the `\thisrow{<name>}` functionality. I think the best thing to do is the following:

1. Read the `data.dat` table into a temporary table macro.
2. Add the label column to the table.
3. Write the modified table to a temporary file using `\pgfplotstablesave`.

(these steps could be wrapped in a convenience macro, of course)

After that, you can access the `names` column exactly like you attempted:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
1 1
2 4
3 7
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{names.dat}
labels
Xyzzy
Plugh
Sheng
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\datatable
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[outfile=temptable,create col/copy column from table={names.dat}{labels}]{names}\datatable
\pgfplotstablesave{\datatable}{temptable}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    visualization depends on=value\thisrow{names}\as\labela,
    nodes near coords=\labela,
]

    \addplot[scatter,only marks] table [x expr=\thisrowno{0},y expr=\thisrowno{1}] {temptable};


    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```